# is there any 802.15.4 RF module (6LoWPAN) for Arduino

Tags: arduino, 6lowpan

I want to make communications between an Arduino and a laptop with the protocol stack 802.15.4-6LoWPAN-IPv6-UDP. I notice that there are some 802.15.4 RF module for Arduino, but almost all of them work with ZigBee. Is there any 802.15.4 RF module for Arduino supporting 6LoWPAN?

Also, I could not find a 802.15.4 dongle (with 6LoWPAN support) for the ubuntu laptop. Any suggestions to make ubuntu be able to send packet through 802.15.4-6LoWPAN?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the 6LoWPAN stack from Telecom Bretagne, which is based on Contiki OS. It is currently the only 6LoWPAN stack, that I have found that is compatible with a Arduino (Mega 2560) or Arduino UNO. However you do need a XBee Series 1 hardware module in order to be able to run the stack.

The 6LoWPAN stack for the Arduino Mega 2560 can be found here:

> https://github.com/telecombretagne/Arduino-IPv6Stack

The 6LoWPAN stack for the Arduino UNO:

> https://github.com/telecombretagne/Arduino-pIPv6Stack

Although you should keep in mind that these codebases haven't seen an update since 2013. So I highly advice you to look into alternative nodes which contain a 802.15.4. RF module e.g. Sky with a CC2420 chip on-board.

A list of nodes compatible with Contiki OS can be found here:

> http://www.contiki-os.org/hardware.html